# Expressing "Both A .. and B"

Tags: grammar, word-choice, difference, sentence-structure

I came across the following sentence:

我既是一个语言的从教者，也是一个语言学习的爱好者。

I understand that "既 A , 也 B" is a [sentence structure for expressing "both .. and .."](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_%22both%E2%80%A6_and%E2%80%A6%22_with_%22ji...you%22).

I was wondering about what effect 既 has on the meaning? Consider the same sentence above with 既 omitted:

我是一个语言的从教者，也是一个语言学习的爱好者。

Has the meaning or feeling of the sentence changed? Is either preferred in some contexts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 我是一个语言的从教者，也是一个语言学习的爱好者。

This sentence reminds us of the fact that I'm also a language hobbyist(assuming I'm well known as a 语言的从教者).

> 我既是一个语言的从教者，也是一个语言学习的爱好者。

With 既, it parallels the two roles (语言的从教者 and 语言学习的爱好者), which share the same level of importance.

Answer (score 0):

Quote:- "Has the meaning or feeling of the sentence changed? Is either preferred in some contexts?"

(1)   the *meaning* has not changed.

(2)   the "*feeling*" may have shifted, if by feeling you mean the thought-processes you wish to convey to or impress upon the listener. The 既是，也是 is to convey to the listener the "contra-duality" of a certain personal circumstance, predicament or function that's significant to you.

Without the 既是, the impact of the contra-duality point you are trying to make is less effective, because it serves to alert the listener that *something* of significance is about to follow.